# AnyLogic Sorting algorithm

Tags: anylogic

In AnyLogic we can perform max and min to find out the largest or smallest value between two values. However, how could I perform sorting of (for example) 5 values, where each value is stored in a variable (for Agent-based modeling)?

Thank you very much in advance. If you think more detail should be provided, also please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

for example with 3 variables called variable1, variable2 and variable3.
Let's add a collection (arrayList) with elements of type double (assuming your variables are of type double)

Each time you want to sort these values:

```
collection.clear(); //clear the collection before adding the variables
collection.add(variable); //add the variables
collection.add(variable1);
collection.add(variable2);
Collections.sort(collection);//sorts the collection from smaller to larger
Collections.reverse(collection);//you can use this code in case you want to sort from larger to smaller instead
```

you can then access the collection by doing

```
collection.get(i)
```

where is it the index of the collection (in this case with 3 variables, it can be 0, 1 or 2)

Comment: I will try this one and see whether it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also curious, after sorting or reversely sorting the 3 variables, how could I extract the values.
In R I can use collection[1], collection[2] ... if the result is a list. How is AnyLogic? Thanks!